# Double pointer to struct

Tags: c, pointers, structure, double-pointer

I have seen this program on the Intel website, but I don't understand some lines. If you couldn't understand the program I appreciate it if you suggest some material to analyze such programs.

The program is written in C language and declares two structures with the name of `Coefficients` and `Roots`, then instantiates double pointers to both of them with `0`. If `Coef_set` and `Root_set` are double pointers, why they refer to the same number zero?

The way the program uses `malloc` is also strange, because it uses double-pointer to structure for type casting (I mean here: `Coef_set = (struct Coefficients **)`) and a pointer to structure in the `sizeof` function. (I mean here: `sizeof(struct Coefficients *)`). Then in a `for` loop gives the parameters of `a`, `b`, `c`, `x1`, and `x2` the value of zero and in the next `for` loop gives other numbers to them. Why it assigns the numbers two times?

```
// Quadratic Equation: a*x^2 + b*x + c = 0
struct Coefficients {
    float a;
    float b;
    float c;
} coefficients;

struct Roots {
    float x1;
    float x2;
} roots;


struct Coefficients ** Coef_set=0;
struct Roots ** Root_set=0;

Coef_set = (struct Coefficients **) malloc(N * sizeof(struct Coefficients *));
Root_set = (struct Roots **) malloc(N * sizeof(struct Roots *));

for (i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    Coef_set[i] = (struct Coefficients *) malloc(sizeof(struct Coefficients));

    Coef_set[i]->a = 0;
    Coef_set[i]->b = 0;
    Coef_set[i]->c = 0;
    
    Root_set[i] = (struct Roots *) malloc(sizeof(struct Roots));

    Root_set[i]->x1 = 0;
    Root_set[i]->x2 = 0;
}

// Initialize the arrays
for (i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    Coef_set[i]->a = (float)(i % 64) + 1.0;
    Coef_set[i]->b = (float)(i % 64) + 101.0;
    Coef_set[i]->c = (float)(i % 32) - 33.0;

    Root_set[i]->x1 = 0;
    Root_set[i]->x2 = 0;
}
```

Comment: "The program is written in C++" -- no it's not.

Comment: It's maybe in C, but it doesn't matter. It should work on C++ too.

Comment: It doesn't work in any of the languages. You can't do `for` loops outside functions and the program is lacking a `main` function.

Comment: It's a fairly weird C: `Coefficients**` here denotes a pointer to an array of pointers. Each struct is allocated separately. I suppose the first loops kinda "initializes" the array (hence the initialization with zeros), and the second loop actually "uses" it.

Comment: A pointer can point to an object, or an array of objects.  A double-pointer is just a pointer to a pointer to an object, or a pointer to an array of pointers each to an object, or a pointer to a pointer to an array of objects, or a pointer to an array of pointers each to an array of objects.  Some folks find it annoying that a pointer is used both ways, but that's one of the ways pointers are flexible.

Comment: Actually all of these codes are inside a main function but for the sake of simplicity, i have omitted some parts.  Down below I will post the whole program. The program wants to solve a equation in the first line for an array of inputs as coefficients.

Comment: Don't omit too much and don't include the whole program (unless it's short). Make a [mcve]. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63094601/edit) the question to include it. Don't post it as an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't update or post the whole program, but I link the Website and at the top there is a file with the name of sample code. In "mySerialApp.c" is the whole program.
https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/tutorial-on-intel-xeon-phi-processor-optimization.html

Comment: `mySerialApp.c` is not a C++ program. It's a C program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines `struct Coefficients ** Coef_set=0;` and `struct Roots ** Root_set=0;` do not set the pointers “to refer to the same number zero.” When used to give a value to a pointer, the constant `0` serves as a null pointer. Each pointer is set to a value, called the null pointer, that indicates it is not pointing to any object.

The following statements, `Coef_set = (struct Coefficients **) malloc(N * sizeof(struct Coefficients *));` and `Root_set = (struct Roots **) malloc(N * sizeof(struct Roots *));`, each allocates memory and sets one of the pointers to point to that memory. Because if this, the initialization of the pointers to the null pointer is of no consequence; that null pointer value is immediately overwritten with a pointer to allocated memory.

Comment: If the pointer do not point to anything why they are initialized with null pointer?
Could you please see the whole program, maybe you could find out why they are initialized. This is the link to website, on the top, there is a file "Sample Code". After dowloading the program is in "mySerialApp.c"
https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/tutorial-on-intel-xeon-phi-processor-optimization.html

Comment: @SobhanNaseri: It is common to initialize a pointer to a null pointer specifically to indicate that it does not point to anything. If a pointer is not initialized, then it does not a valid value. If `x` is not initialized, we cannot write code that will test `x` to see if it points to something or if it does not. Initializing a pointer means that other code can later test it to see if it is pointing to something or not. As I wrote, there is no need to initialize a pointer when it is immediately assigned a different value anyway. Some authors simply do this as a matter of habit or practice.

Answer (score 0):

The whole code can reduced to:

```
struct Coefficients {
    float a;
    float b;
    float c;
};

struct Roots {
    float x1;
    float x2;
};

typedef struct 
{
    struct Coefficients coefficients;
    struct Roots roots;
}equasion;



equasion *foo(size_t N)
{
    equasion *equasions = calloc(N, sizeof(*equasions));

    // Initialize the arrays
    for (size_t i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        equasions[i].coefficients.a = (float)(i % 64 + 1);
        equasions[i].coefficients.b = (float)(i % 64 + 101);
        equasions[i].coefficients.c = (float)(i % 32 - 33);
    }
    return equasions;
}
```

There is no need of double pointers, array of pointers and individually malloced structs. Zeroing is not needed as there is the `calloc` function. Types should not be used in the `sizeof`. Use objects instead.

Comment: I think, if you see the whole program, you understand that it was intentionally written like this, and reduced form can not fulfill all the requirements. The whole programm is the sample code here in "mySerialApp.c"
https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/tutorial-on-intel-xeon-phi-processor-optimization.html